# Windows Phone - Getting Device Location by showing Street Names and not Co-ordinates?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, location, maps

I was just wandering how I can get the current location of the device. Now, when I tried to do this using Geolocator it didn't work. It just gave me the Longitude and Latitude. I don't want this I want the names of the street or city or suburb etc... an example would be the `HERE Transit` app by Nokia. When you go to the 'Nearby' tab, you get a map and beneath that is the street name, suburb and then city and postcode.

How can I do this? what I have right now is:

```
        Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
        geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;
        try
        {
            Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
            test.Text = geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.00");
            testt.Text = geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.00");
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {

        }
```

Basically this gives me the Longitude and Latitude. Maybe I can use these to get the names of the street or city etc but HOW?

I've never really used the MAPS or anything to do with Location when programming. So how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called reverse geocoding.
Here is a sample code that does that:

```
MapAddress address;
ReverseGeocodeQuery query = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
query.GeoCoordinate = myGeoCoordinate;
query.QueryCompleted += (s, e) =>
   {
        if (e.Error != null)
            return;

        address = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
    };
query.QueryAsync();
```

That API is available on Windows Phone 8 and I see the question is tagged WP7 but since you seem to use the `Geolocator` API, I guess you are on WP8. Otherwise, you'd have to use this kind of service: [Find a Location by Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx)

Comment: Thank You! Exactly what I wanted!

Comment: With Windows Phone 8 this works in offline mode too?